# Is there a way to limit the length of a string from a jaxb class?

Tags: java, jaxb

How do you specify facets for the xsd in an annotated jaxb java class?

I'd like to limit a String to only 1 character using annotations (and not from an xsd). Is this possible?

Comment: http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_3-Defining-a-String-with-Length-Limits.html

Comment: @HunterMcMillen i think he asked if you can do it by annotation.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I actually looked at that page already, but it didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: @gigadot Yes, that's what I meant. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an implementation of [Bean Validation (JSR-303)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) for this use case.   It allows you to specify validation rules via annotations or XML for object properties.  Hibernate implemented the reference implementation:

- http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html